# Recommend a DB to process large data from MySQL

Tags: data-preprocessing, database

Basically, right now I'm working with data that has reached 1+ TB on MySQL and I need to run a statistical algorithm on it in the future. I also need to process the data as well.

What I'm hoping to do is port it over to a NoSQL database. I was looking either at Redis or MongoDB. Another thought would be to use Hadoop.

The data itself is composed of some JSON fields and also int values mainly. The data does not need to stay in the same form, actually I will change it anyway so I can work(hopefully) with the transformations needed to go to NoSQL.

I was wondering what recommendations people had to do this? Advantages/disadvantages? I will be creating the algorithm itself in Python or R by the way.

Thanks

Comment: That will be a tough problem to do in R (open source) or Python. Try to build your algo on a sample instead.

Comment: The [datascience](http://datascience.stackexchange.com/) SE may be a better venue for this question?

Answer (score 1):

At 1TB, I'd say Hadoop is an overkill. MongoDb is ok, you can get reasonable query performance and at the same time also be setup to scale reasonably easily. Mongo has bindings for Python for sure. But remember that Mongo is a general purpose NoSQL database and you will not find out of the box support for many ML tasks like the Hadoop ecosystem does.

It is therefore a tradeoff between convenience (Mongo is easy to get to from MySQL) and long term requirements.

I don't have any personal experience with redis, but it is primarily an in memory store.